# Get spring application context on a ServletContextListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the spring application context on a ServletContextListener. I am using Spring with annotation configuration. Using this code i get "context null". What I am doing wrong?

```
@WebListener
public class Initializer implements ServletContextListener
{   
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("context " + WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your ordering of the listeners is wrong. The `ContextLoaderListener` should be executed before this listener.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for fix the problem has been delete the annotation `@WebListener` and on `WebAppInitializer` override `onStartup` to ensure that the `ContextLoaderListener` is loaded before `Initializer`

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException
    {
        super.onStartup(container);
        container.addListener(Initializer.class);
    }
}
```